# linking to GSL library using lccwin64 compiler

Tags: c, gsl, lcc-win32

Linking to the Gnu Scientific Library is very well documented using gcc for Linux & Cygwin.

Here, I'm working on Windows 7, and all I have is the `lcc` compiler (http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/ , which includes lcc64 and lcclnk64) and GSL libraries for Windows 64bits (https://code.google.com/p/oscats/downloads/detail?name=gsl-1.15-dev-win64.zip&can=2&q=).

I do not have cygwin/mingw/msys/Visual Studio.

My question pertains to `lcc` and the libraries found in `gsl-1.15-dev-win64.zip`. The test code is

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>

 int main (void)
 {
     double a = 20;
     double b = 10;
     double x = 0.5;
     double result = gsl_sf_beta_inc(a, b, x);
     printf("%f\n", result);
     return 0;
 }
```

Compiling isn't the problem. Linking to the gsl static library using `lcclnk64` is the question. I've tried variation of the following:

```
 lcclnk64 test.obj -Lc:\gsl\lib -lgsl
```

first compiling with `lcc64` then linking, or running the entire process with one `lc64` call, using `libgsl.dll.a`, `libgsl.a`, `lgsl` and `libgsl.lib` after renaming `libgsl.dll.a` to `libgsl.lib`, and with/without `-subsystem console`. I still get:

```
 connect test.obj .text: undefined reference to 'gsl_sf_beta_inc'
```

I'd like to link to a static GSL library to obtain a standalone `exe`, on Windows 7 and using `lcc`, and not have to send dlls with the exe if I have to share the `exe`. Getting `test.obj` is easy, it's getting the object linked to `libgsl.???` that is totally stymieing me. Thanks for any pointers.

EDIT:

I got the following to compile and link without error, but when I run `test.exe` I get an error dialog telling me a DLL is missing and I need to reinstall the program.

```
 lcc64 test.c -Ic:\gsl\include
 lcclnk64 test.obj libgsl.lib -Lc:\gsl\lib -subsystem console
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are unable to get the desired information for your compiler, you could go here:

http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds

and select/download/install the compiler of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. I did get the GSL 1.8 libs to work with mingw (the only GSL libs I could find online), but would like to see the same happen with lcc.